# Golang split string if there is no indentation

Tags: regex, algorithm, go, split

I have a log file like this.

```sh
INFO [com.cplus.sdk.iso.module] 02:55:24.8290 19.02.2022 @ com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module
  [Message] message sent
  [Source] [Protocol:TranzWare-InterConnect (v.2.115-11);Client:[Transport:TCP/IP;To:/127.0.0.1:50274;From:/127.0.0.1:4455;KeepAlive:true;Framer:L2 L1 <###>]]
  [Thread] IA-Pool-Thread-18 (30)
INFO [com.cplus.sdk.net] 02:55:25.7840 19.02.2022 @ com.cplus.sdk.net.Client
  [Message] connection closed
  [Source] [Transport:TCP/IP;Closed;To:/172.30.250.35:57001;From:/10.1.180.54:49851;KeepAlive:true;Framer:(Len+1) L2 L1 <###> ETX]
  [Thread] IA-Pool-Thread-4 (16)
SEVERE [com.cplus.ia] 02:55:25.9530 19.02.2022 @ com.cplus.ia.Instance$InterfaceListener$2
  [Message] interface processing error
  [Source] Instance:[UnitID:11276;External:{ExternalHost:[Protocol:Alto-Rtt (v.1.0);Interface:ISO-8583 Based Host-To-Host Interface]}]
  [Thread] IA-Pool-Thread-4 (16)
  [Exception] com.cplus.sdk.ex.ProcessorException com.cplus.ia.tic.Interface.handle <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Processor.process <- com.cplus.ia.tic.Interface.process <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module.process <- com.cplus.ia.Instance$InterfaceListener$2.run <- java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call[Executors.java<511>] <- java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run[FutureTask.java<266>] <- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker[ThreadPoolExecutor.java<1149>] <- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run[ThreadPoolExecutor.java<624>] <- com.cplus.ia.Instance$ApplicationThread.run <- java.lang.Thread.run[Thread.java<748>]
    [Text] unhandled processing error
    [Cause] com.cplus.sdk.ex.NetworkException com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module.send <- com.btpn.alto.rtt.TicInterface.msgHandler[TicInterface.java<329>] <- com.btpn.alto.rtt.TicInterface.onFinancial[TicInterface.java<183>] <- com.cplus.ia.tic.Interface.handle <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Processor.process <- com.cplus.ia.tic.Interface.process <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module.process <- com.cplus.ia.Instance$InterfaceListener$2.run <- java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call[Executors.java<511>] <- java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run[FutureTask.java<266>] <- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker[ThreadPoolExecutor.java<1149>] <- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run[ThreadPoolExecutor.java<624>] <- com.cplus.ia.Instance$ApplicationThread.run <- java.lang.Thread.run[Thread.java<748>]
      [Cause] java.nio.channels.InterruptedByTimeoutException com.cplus.sdk.net.FramesHelper.checkDeadline <- com.cplus.sdk.net.FramesHelper$IO.write <- com.cplus.sdk.net.Frames$Frame27.write <- com.cplus.sdk.net.Client.write <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module$ModuleTCP.sendMessage <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module.send <- com.btpn.alto.rtt.TicInterface.msgHandler[TicInterface.java<329>] <- com.btpn.alto.rtt.TicInterface.onFinancial[TicInterface.java<183>] <- com.cplus.ia.tic.Interface.handle <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Processor.process <- com.cplus.ia.tic.Interface.process <- com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module.process <- com.cplus.ia.Instance$InterfaceListener$2.run <- java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call[Executors.java<511>] <- java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run[FutureTask.java<266>] <- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker[ThreadPoolExecutor.java<1149>] <- java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run[ThreadPoolExecutor.java<624>] <- com.cplus.ia.Instance$ApplicationThread.run <- java.lang.Thread.run[Thread.java<748>]
FINE [com.cplus.sdk.net] 05:27:34.0200 27.03.2022 @ com.cplus.sdk.net.Client
  [Message] frame sent: QTRNMTAwMDAwODAwODIyMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA0MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMzI2MjIyNzM0MzAwNzkzMzAx
  [Source] [Transport:TCP/IP;To:/127.0.0.1:56573;From:/127.0.0.1:2221;KeepAlive:true;Framer:L2 L1 <###>]
  [Thread] IA-Pool-Thread-2 (45)
INFO [com.cplus.sdk.iso.module] 05:27:34.0200 27.03.2022 @ com.cplus.sdk.iso.Module
  [Message] message sent
  [Source] [Protocol:TranzWare-InterConnect (v.2.115-11);Client:[Transport:TCP/IP;To:/127.0.0.1:56573;From:/127.0.0.1:2221;KeepAlive:true;Framer:L2 L1 <###>]]
  [Thread] IA-Pool-Thread-2 (45)
```

I want to split and group it based on if the next line is not a \t character. In javascript I can use regex in split method, but golang Split in strings built-in function only receive string as separator. What I've tried so far was

```golang
strings.SplitAfter(log, ")")
```

But the code above doesn't capture the SEVERE state completely.
I'm thinking to loop through each character and looking for alphabet character and append it to a slice but I think it will be too slow.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to do this if you want; something like the following should work [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IuScVPvZ0Z5)

```golang
regexp.MustCompile("([^ ].*[\r|\n].(?: .*[\r|\n]*)*)").FindAllString(input, -1)
```

(Note that the above uses spaces rather than tabs because that's what I got when I copied the data from your question).

Alternatively you can write your own code; the source of the standard library would be a [good starting point](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/strings/strings.go;l=315).

Comment: Thank you @Brits it works wonderfully. Like you said it is indeed spaces rather than tabs, my bad. Btw, what is -1 does in FindAllString?

Comment: This is covered in [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#pkg-overview) "These routines take an extra integer argument, n. If n >= 0, the function returns at most n matches/submatches; otherwise, it returns all of them." - so `-1` means 'return all'.